# webclient.downloadfile check if not downloaded

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have code as follows:

`client.DownloadFile(Convert.ToString(DR(1)), "c:\images\" & name)`

I want to check if the file was actually downloaded, something like:

`If client.downloadFile = 0 then`

The reason for this is that there is a stored procedure that get's all URL's from my database and then it should download them, let's say that one row does not contain a URL then it should just write to my `log()` that the file was not downloaded locally.

Is this possible or is there a method to use?

I don't mind C# help.

Comment: If your URL is empty, you can simple check for empty and save the message to log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below mentioned code it may help you

```
 webClient.DownloadDataAsync(myUri);
    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) =>
                                       {
                                        //check your condition...
                                       };
```

Comment: thanks, would you please explain the line 2? dont want to copy code and not know what it does.

Comment: it will excucted when your downloaddata completed it's lambda expression when download completed you will get the result from e.Result